# Joomla 4 custom fields in module

Tags: custom-field

Good day.
Help with custom fields and helper
**mod_statesites.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="module" version="4.0" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <name>MOD_STATESITES</name>
    <description>MOD_STATESITES_XML_DESCRIPTION</description>
    <namespace path="src">Joomla\Module\StateSites</namespace>
    <files>
        <filename module="mod_statesites">mod_statesites.php</filename>
        <folder>tmpl</folder>
        <folder>images</folder>
        <folder>assets</folder>
        <folder>language</folder>
        <folder>src</folder>
        <filename>mod_statesites.xml</filename>
    </files>
    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_statesites/models/fields">
                <field name="bggradientview" 
                    type="bggradient" 
                />            
    
</extension>
```

helper scr/Helper/StateSitesHelper.php

```
<?php

namespace Joomla\Module\StateSites\Site\Helper;
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Helper\ModuleHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Router\Route;

\defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class StateSitesHelper
{
    public static function getModuleTitle()
    {
        return $module->title;
    }

    public static function getParam($ParamName)
    {
        return $params->get($ParamName);
    }
}
```

Custom field models/fields/bggradient.php

```
<?php
defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Form\FormField as JFormField;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\Helper\ModuleHelper;
use Joomla\Module\StateSites\Site\Helper\StateSitesHelper;

class JFormFieldBggradient extends JFormField
{
    protected $type = 'bggradient';

    protected function getInput()
    {

        $html = '
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #dee2e6;border-radius: 0.375rem;padding: 6px;margin: 2px;">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
                        <div id="bggradient-gradus">' . Text::_('MOD_STATESITES_BGGRADUS2') . '120</div>
                        <div id="bggradient-view" style="background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgba(3, 169, 244, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 235, 59, 1) 100%);height: 60px;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="bggradient-color" name="bggradient-color" value="' . StateSitesHelper::getParam('bgcolor') . '" />

            </div>                
    ';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Error - Class 'Joomla\Module\StateSites\Site\Helper\StateSitesHelper' not found
**error in line input type="hidden"**

Help solve the problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Is the code directory `src` or `scr`? `models` directory isn't even included in the manifest.